# How to handle parameters in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
**Request
Parameters:**

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"rXhIA6/LAP8Kla9kMExq16bpr51WeFyPo0vDi9sE86c=",
 "id"=>"2",
 "user"=>{"role_id"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Change Role"}
```

How can I get the parameter 3 from **"role_id"** in the controller?
I tried

```
 @role = (params[:user])
```

but I only get

```
 {"role_id"=>"2"}
```

Comment: try  `@role = (params[:user][:role_id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@role = params[:user][:role_id]
```

gives you the result `@role = 3`